# Search for a value and move it to another spreadsheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a little problem using Excel 2010. The problem is simple but I think I start in a wrong direction. Let's say I have a document with the following structure:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th> Col A</th>
    <th> Col B</th>
    <th> Col C</th>
  </thead>
    <tr> 
      <td> NONE</td>
      <td> TEST</td>
      <td> NONE</td>
      <td> TEST2</td>
      <td> TEST3</td>
      <td> TEST4</td>
   </tr>
  
  <tr> 
      <td> NONE</td>
      <td> TEST</td>
      <td> NONE</td>
      <td> TEST2</td>
      <td> TEST3</td>
      <td> TEST4</td>
   </tr>
  
  <tr> 
      <td> TEST</td>
      <td> TEST</td>
      <td> NONE</td>
      <td> TEST2</td>
      <td> TEST3</td>
      <td> TEST4</td>
   </tr>
  
  <tbody>
  </tbody>  
  
</table>
```

I want to search for `NONE` and move it to another spreadsheet. I want to do this with formula. I tried with SEACH but I don't know how to move it to another spreadsheet.

Comment: Hey, I considered but i am curious if a formula will resolve my problem.

Comment: Suppose you have a Worksheet with you sample data, then what event should trigger that cell move? Please clarify your business logic (at this point I agree with @pnuts - Formula cannot move the cell). Best regards,